# How to fix "Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist" while running others project, what to do?

Tags: xcode, react-native, emulation, cfbundleidentifier

I'm trying to launch project from github and this problem occurs: 
[image: error]

Error occurs after running via `react-native run-ios`
I tried to launch it on different simulators - didn't work
Reinstalling node_models - didn't work
`react-native upgrade` - didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for me switching version of **XCode** worked great (from `10.1` to `9.2`), while none of any other methods from the web did

thank you all

Answer (score 2):

Here's what you need to do 
go to your cd to node_modules/react-native/third-party/glog-0.*.* and run ./configure

Answer (score 1):

If you have any working react-native project then copy `node_modules/react-native/` folder and replace with current project..

I know it's not a solution but that's how I am doing it right now. I am also looking for solution. Right now, it's working for me with this.